# delayed_job update query is running infinitely

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job and delayed_job_active_record for back ground job execution in my rails application. We are using queue based delayed_job. For starting the delayed I am using the following command.

```
RAILS_ENV=staging script/delayed_job -i=1 --queue=queue_name start
```

The problem is below query is firing infinitely.

```
SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `locked_at` = '2013-04-16 09:27:23', `locked_by` = 'delayed_job.=2 host:ip-10-204-210-77 pid:2168' WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`queue` IN ('queue_name') AND ((run_at <= '2013-04-16 09:27:23' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-04-16 05:27:23') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job.=2 host:ip-10-204-210-77 pid:2168') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

And the delayed_job count is zero. Because of this the application is very slow and the pages are not loading in many places.

Comment: Care to try delayed_job_active_record_threaded and see this helps? I would love to hear your feedback =) https://github.com/zxiest/delayed_job_active_record_threaded

Comment: Same thing here. It's deceiving because there are no jobs and it's trying to do an `UPDATE` as well. Just generates a lot of unnecessary noise in the logs.

Comment: @Menon did you manage to get to a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you meant is that `delayed_job` *polls too frequently* (which by the way is every `5` seconds by default) - I know that fills up your log, and *seems* "infinite".. :)

If that is what you meant, then I suggest you run the [workless gem](https://github.com/lostboy/workless). It will only start `delayed_job` on a per need basis. Many people use it to keep their [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) worker dynos from running idle, but it works just as well in `development` mode.

Note that if you are using [delayed_job_active_record](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record), you also need to add `gem 'daemons'` to your `Gemfile` ([daemons](https://rubygems.org/gems/daemons)). See the [Running Jobs section of `delayed_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

Thus, your `Gemfile` would contain:

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'workless'
```

If you need more guidance, let me know in the comments below.

Answer (score 2):

i had to use AR's `silence` method, just change in file `[path/to/delayed_job_active_record/gem]/delayed_job_active_record-[any.latest.version]/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb` around line 68:

```
count = ready_scope.limit(1).update_all(:locked_at => now, :locked_by => worker.name)
```

to

```
count = silence {ready_scope.limit(1).update_all(:locked_at => now, :locked_by => worker.name)}
```

dirty solution, i know, but it works... welcome to propose a better wrapper, but for me `Job.reserve` method there is big enough to kill any thoughts to override it in `config/initializers`

Answer (score 1):

So this is a query specifically designed for Postgres. Please refer to https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/blob/master/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb#L57 for why it has to be like that.

The idea of delayed job is indeed that it will query the db periodically, so the query in your question is expected to be fired as long as the worker is running. This should happen every second and I can't imagine that this has significant influence on the performance of your app.

Are you running on very limited hardware like a very small virtual machine?

Comment: Not a virtual machine. small instance in amazon. And I am using Mysql not postgres.

Comment: I see, perhaps it is slow because it is swapping to the disk? Did you check the memory footprint of the ruby processes?

Answer (score 0):

> I faced same issue and i resolved it by adding index on queue field.

```
def self.up
  create_table :delayed_jobs, :force => true do |table|
  # Add index on queue field
  add_index :delayed_jobs, [:queue], :name => 'delayed_jobs_queue'
end
```

For more information visit below document http://himarsh.org/cautions-on-delayed-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

In your delayed job binstub set the log level to 'info' to remove those constant logging statements.  You can still leave your main Rails apps at any log level you prefer... info, debug, etc. This change will only affect the logging level for delayed job.

in `bin/delayed_job`:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'

# ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE...
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.logger.level = Logger::INFO

Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```