# Frequently polls happening from delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Hi I am using [delayed job active record gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) in my production application with Postgres, a lot of background jobs are working through the delayed job

One thing I have noticed in the output of pg:outliers in our production database, the prop_exec_time is 4.5% for this query and almost 1.8 million calls happened in 45 hours.

Query:

`UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = $1, locked_by = $2 WHERE id IN (SELECT  id FROM "delayed_jobs"  WHERE ((run_at <= $3 AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < $4) OR locked_by = $5) AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT $6 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *`

As per the delayed job, the polls happen every 5 seconds by default, but this happens even if there is no job to perform. Currently, there is no extra configuration in our app.

I guess I can override the default time of delayed_job, will this make any impact? Any kind of suggestion to reduce the calls

Comment: Yes I am using that gem @jjanes, I have updated there

Answer (score 0):

> the prop_exec_time is 4.5% for this query and almost 1.8 million calls happened in 45 hours.

4.5% does not seem outrageous.  Is there really a problem here which needs to be solved?

How many jobs went through the queue during that 45 hours?  Was the queue completely empty for that whole time?  The poll is every 5 seconds **per worker**, so getting 1.8 million calls on an empty queue in 45 hours would take 50 workers.  Do you have that many?

> I guess I can override the default time of delayed_job, will this make any impact?

Yes, but it will also delay the responsiveness to your workers detecting new work to do.

Comment: we are using the maximum of 18 * 2x workers, managing through process scheduler. Answer is for your question "Is there really a problem here which needs to be solved?" actually I guess even if there is no job to process, that time also this query is running, which I can see in my local, so is there any way to stop the UPDATE if there is no job?

Comment: It can't know there is no job to process without checking to see, and they way it checks to see is by running the query.  In theory you could use the NOTIFY/LISTEN feature of PostgreSQL to wake up processes when a new job arrives, but I don't think delayed_job implements that.  And doing that would add more overhead to the case where the queue is rarely empty.

Comment: Ok, recently I noticed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033610/delayed-job-update-query-is-running-infinitely feels kind of same thing, anything will be benefit for the question